# Cannot get matplotlib graphics to show up inline

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to load automatically the command lines with Jupyter in Ubuntu 16.10 :

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

With Ubuntu, we could normally use configuration files as `.vimrc`, `.bashrc` and so on to automate some command lines. I know we could create the config file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` with `jupyter notebook --generate-config`. How could we implement that in python in that `.py` file?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you want figures inline in the command line? That's not possible; it's a reason why people use notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have graphics inline in a regular terminal because regular terminals don't have graphics capabilities. However, if you would be willing to use an alternative console, [Jupyter Qtconsole](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/), may be suitable for you.

EDIT: okay, I've had a look and you need to look at [this](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html), specifically the parts about running files/lines of code at startup. (like `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines` or `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files`

Comment: Sorry, but this is exactly I wanted to say. I am using Jupyter Qtconsole normally. Could you tell me how to do that in the '.jupyterqtconsolerc' file (if it exists)?